# Filling out a calendar with custom information

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, python-requests

I am trying to create a calendar for a webpage with custom information on it. I don't have a strong enough background in css to build a decent calendar, so I turned to the Google embedded calendar. My webpage has a calendar link to my account, but I want to import my own ical file. This file is generated automatically in a script, and I want to add functionality to import the .ics. I currently use selenium to get to the page (https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings/export?tab=wc) but I can't get selenium to capture the window where I select my file. My next idea was to write the file path to the input section then click the import button but the import tag is hidden and I can't seem to find a way to get selenium to find it. My next solution was to use requests.post, but there isn't a clear url to post to. I am stuck, so help with any of the four problems would be much appreciated!

Problems:

1) a decent calendar with event information that is easy to code in css and html or a calendar that can be embedded and accepts .ics

2) a way to capture the file explorer window to type my own path into

3) find hidden input tag to put file path into (and how to make sure the file is uploaded)

4) find the url of the server that the POST method calls

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Are you trying to code up your own calendar, or are you trying to automate google calendar? Asking 4 questions in a single post isn't usually the best way to ask here, especially when the questions are all quite different in nature. I'm not sure what the end goal is here.

Comment: I am trying to get a calendar with my events on my website, and I had two possible solutions. The first was to code up my own calendar but I do not have a clue how to make it look good, so I was looking for a thorough guide or something. Since that seemed like a dead end, I tried automating google calendar because I can embed that in my website. TLDR I tried other stuff but right now I am automating google calendar

Answer (score 0):

While I can't answer all 4 of your questions, I can help with #3:

```
# find the input
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")

# execute script to reveal hidden element -- this part might be optional
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", input)

# send file path keys to the input
input.send_keys("C:/Path/To/Your/File")

# verify if the upload was successful
uploaded_file = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']/preceding-sibling::span[not(contains(@aria-hidden, 'true'))]")))

if (uploaded_file.text == file_name): # file_name is the name of file, like Test.txt
    print("File upload was successful")
```

This code will locate the `input` element which accepts your file upload, and execute some Javascript to reveal the element -- this works around any `ElementNotVisible` or `ElementNotInteractable` exceptions we may encounter. Then, we `send_keys` to the input element -- it accepts your full, absolute file path to the item you are trying to upload.

Then, we verify the upload, by checking the `span` element which appears, containing the name of the uploaded file. If this element exists, and its `.text` attribute equals the name of the file you uploaded (like `Test.txt`), then the upload was successful.

`uploaded_file.text` returns `Select file from your computer` if the file was not uploaded. This text changes to `Test.text` when the file has been uploaded successfully.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I got it working so now I just need to figure out what is wrong with my .ics file. Also apologies for the confusion about my question, I thought it might give me a solution faster to have multiple possible solutions (though this was more than fast enough for me)